# cut -f 2- -d " "

Tags: linux, bash, find, cut

I have the following script called often

### cleanup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
DEFAULT_LIMIT=10
INPUT=$1
PATTERN=$2
LIMIT=$3

if [ "$INPUT" == "" ] || [ "$PATTERN" == "" ]
then
        echo "usage: $0 INPUT PATTERN [LIMIT]"
        exit 1;
fi
if [ "$LIMIT" == "" ]
then
        LIMIT=$DEFAULT_LIMIT
fi

find /var/project/project1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "${INPUT}-${PATTERN}*" -printf '%T@ %p\n'|sort -nr|tail -n+$LIMIT|cut -f 2- -d " "|xargs -i rm -rf {}
```

So this one is supposed to remove the last but `$LIMIT` directories with prefix `$INPUT-$PATTERN` from `/var/project/project1` and very rarely unexpectedly (though very crucial) it removes directories other than the intended one from `/var/project/project1`. Any idea why? Is the behavior of cut well defined for 2-?  can we have spaces between f and the field#? This was not written intentionally but a bug but not quite sure if this piece of code is the one causing this unexpected deletes.

This is very rarely reproducible and hence not sure if fixing this (`cut -f2 -d " "`) is going to solve my problem

Comment: Is there any chance that any of your files could ever have a filename that contains a space? Because your `xargs` command would interpret (say) `/var/project/project1/foo bar` as two separate files to delete: `/var/project/project/foo`, and `bar`.

Comment: @ruakh - Yes, that is likely where his unexpected behavior comes from.

Comment: No none of the files in the list selected list will contain spaces

Answer (score 3):

Your current implementation will break on any files that have spaces. This is the nature of `xargs`, and why it is considered dangerous unless -0 is used (which wouldn't be possible in your current layout).

As an example, lets say that a file makes it to `xargs` called "foo bar". `xargs` will call rm like this:

```
rm -rf foo bar
```

Instead of deleting "foo bar", it deletes a file called `foo` and a file called `bar`. If you change your cut command to `-f2` instead of `-f2-`, it will still break on files with spaces, but would only delete `foo`.

Here is an example that will handle all possible filenames:

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$1
pattern=$2
limit=${3:-10} # use 10 if $3 is not set

if [[ -z $input || -z $pattern ]]
then
        echo "usage: $0 INPUT PATTERN [LIMIT]"
        exit 1;
fi

dirs=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' latest # \0 is used as a delimiter, since it is not valid in a filename
do 
   dirs+=("$latest") # append files to the array in mtime sorted order, oldest first
done < <(find /var/project/project1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "${input}-${pattern}*" -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -zn)

dirs=("${dirs[@]#* }") # remove mtime from the elements
rm -rf "${dirs[@]:0:$limit}"
```

Comment: @shyamprasad It cuts from field 2 to the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `echo "one" | cut -f 2 -d " "` will display "one" even though we ask for the second field.

So what do you expect when you when you call `cut -f 2- -d " "` and there is only one field? If nothing then add the `-s` option.

In other words change

```
cut -f 2- -d " "
```

to

```
cut -s -f 2- -d " "
```

Hope it helps.